# What is the best LTS ubuntu version to upgrade to, when the presently installed one has only 2 months left?

Tags: 18.04, apt, 20.04, upgrade, ppa

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, which I upgraded originally from Ubuntu 14.04.

Presently (February 2021), Ubuntu 16.04 will run out of support in less than two months.

I could now upgrade to 18.04 or 20.04.

- Upgrading to 20.04 will allow me to have no upgrade hassle for the next 4 years.
- If I upgrade to 20.04, I will have a state of the art system where I do not have to add `ppa`s  too early, when I need a newer functionality (which in general could be a security issue, if I use the wrong ppa by chance).
- Upgrading to 18.04 should deliver to me less hassle in the daily business, because all the software that I use (apart from Ubuntu directly), had already two additional years to adapt to everything that Ubuntu 18.04 has as a standard (higher python version, higher R version, ... just to name some).
- In general, *upgrading* one aspect of the system by the use of `ppa`s is possible, *downgrading* makes more difficulties.

Which is the best strategy to follow - or do I miss an aspect or weight some aspects non-canonically?

**EDIT**

I presently do not have an idea how I could change the question to get it reopened again.
If somebody else feels in the mood to comment, I would appreciate it much.
If somebody has an idea where else I could ask this question, a comment would be helpful for me, too.

Thanks to all previous and coming commentators!

Comment: If you are sure your hardware can support it I would upgrade to 20.04 that is just my option and what I have done with the 6 machines I have here. They were 16.04 and now are 20.04

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 **had** two upgrade paths, (1) to the next release or 16.10 which is now EOL so that upgrade path is now gone.  (2) to the next LTS release, which is 18.04 LTS.   Those were your two options, of which now only one exists.   From 18.04 you originally had two options; but one has now gone.... however you're not on 18.04 so that point is moot anyway.  Your question doesn't make sense unless you're talking about *upgrade via re-install* options; are you?

Comment: If you need Gtk2, Python2, Chromium as deb-package, Qt4 - then Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the best version. But be careful with R here. Downgrade its packages with Synaptic first. Then upgrade the system. As the result you will have R 3.4.4 from official Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @N0rbert's comment was the most helpful I feel, as the end-use of your system will control which it's best to move to.  If you're using 'universe' packages, then *bionic* makes less sense as those packages get shorter life spans & most will be EOL in 2021-April (ie. 3 years for 'universe' is normal, 5 applies to 'main', but 3 years doesn't apply to all in 'universe' either).  16.04 can only upgrade to 18.04 currently (so 20.04 is moot from 16.04 unless you're willing to *upgrade via re-install*). PPAs need to be evaluated manually so we can't help there (they're 3rd party).

Comment: Your question was vague in my opinion thus only opinions could be expressed; which aren't on-topic here.  Ubuntu Forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/) may have been a better fit for your question as asked.